# How to forbid empty strings in json file?

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json`. `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` only makes sure that the element isn't null, but I also want to check for empty strings in order to disallow them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you try use "ItemRequired = Required.Always" instead "Required"? Also you can check in your property if string is empty , set value as null

Comment: One solution may be to create a generic custom converter